# PHP and XML feed for newbie

Tags: php, xml

I'm an old timer ;) making the switch from ASP/vbscript/MSAccess!

I need some help to get me started to navigate through an [XML feed](http://feed.harjbains.gnomen-europe.com/xml-feed).

Using the code below:

```
$feed = file_get_contents("http://feed.harjbains.gnomen-europe.com/xml-feed/");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

// Display the first post title
echo $xml->channel->item[0]->title;
```

I get an error stating:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 19350: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document

Am I going about this all the wrong way??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the XML you receive is wrongly formated... Have a look at what it returns. You have a XML and at the bottom you also have HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of [that URL](http://feed.harjbains.gnomen-europe.com/xml-feed/). Near the end, there is some extra HTML content. That is causing the error message to appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<properties>
    <total>298</total>

    <property>
        <category>1</category>
        <id>1174</id>
```

... skipping to near the end:

```
</properties>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>xml-feed - Harj Bains Estate Agents</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../../media/feed.harjbains.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->



    <meta name="Generator" content="Gnomen CMS 4 | Estate Agency Edition - Gnomen Ltd copyrights 2015." />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/common.js"></script>
    <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="Description" content="" />


    <!--Map Icon-->
    <script>
        var icon = [];
        icon[0] = new GIcon();
        icon[0].image = "/media/feed.harjbains.com/images/default/map-icon.png";
        icon[0].iconSize = new GSize(60, 40);
        icon[0].iconAnchor = new GPoint(0, 0);
        icon[0].infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(10, 10);
    </script>
    <!--Map Icon End-->
</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

> Am I going about this all the wrong way??

That depends on what the "*wrong way*" is. One solution to avoid the error might be to strip out the excess content (i.e. HTML).